# How to draw JSON text in Java Canvas?

Tags: java, android, json, android-canvas, pretty-print

How can I write a `JSON` object/string with pretty formatted in `Android Canvas`?

For example,

```
val jsonText = "{"profile":{"name": "Robert","account_id": "31"}}"
```

will be drawn to a `Canvas` which looks like,

[image]

Comment: Maybe use an existing online Json viewer and a Webview on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Generate PDF

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder    

class PdfGeneratorService(){

    private val ROW_INC = 20F
    private val COL_INC = 15F
    
    fun jsonFormat(jsonStr: String): String {

        var indentCount = 0

        val builder = StringBuilder()
        for (c in jsonStr) {
            if (indentCount > 0 && '\n' == builder.last()) {
                for (x in 0..indentCount) builder.append("    ")
            }
            when (c) {
                '{', '[' -> {
                    builder.append(c).append("\n")
                    indentCount++
                }
                ',' -> builder.append(c).append("\n")
                '}', ']' -> {
                    builder.append("\n")
                    indentCount--
                    for (x in 0..indentCount) builder.append("    ")
                    builder.append(c)
                }
                else -> builder.append(c)
            }
        }

        return builder.toString()
    }

    private fun createPdf(textToPdf: String) {
        try {
            val gSon = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
            val text = gSon.toJson(jsonFormat(textToPdf))

            val rawLines = text.split("\\n")
            val jsonLines = rawLines.map { it.replace("\\", "") }
            val maxLengthString = jsonLines.maxBy { it.length }

            val paint = Paint()
            paint.color = Color.BLACK
            paint.fontSpacing

            val pageWidth = paint.measureText(maxLengthString).toInt() + 2 * COL_INC.toInt() // 2, two side padding
            val pageHeight = (ROW_INC * rawLines.size + ROW_INC).toInt()

            val document = PdfDocument()
            val pageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, 1).create()
            val page: PdfDocument.Page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
            val canvas = page.canvas

            for (line in jsonLines) {
                canvas.drawText(line, column, row, paint)
                row += ROW_INC
            }

            document.finishPage(page)
            document.writeTo(FileOutputStream(File(PATH_TO_PDF_FILE)))
            document.close()
        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            Log.e("classTag", e)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find article of how to use [Gson](https://medium.com/@hissain.khan/parsing-with-google-gson-library-in-android-kotlin-7920e26f5520)

Answer (score 2):

> Canvas functions have some limitations as it draws all text in single line. If the width of the text exceeds the width of the Canvas, the text will be clipped. hence we use staticLayout for the same to show text in paragraph or multi-line approach.

Below code works to show json formatted text in canvas, where json is loading from asset file.

```
fun drawTextOnCanvas(activity: FragmentActivity) {
var canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
var textPaint=TextPaint()
textPaint.density=20f
textPaint.bgColor=Color.BLACK

val jsonText = activity.loadJSONFromAsset("demo.json")
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonText);
val text=jsonObject.toString(1)
val staticLayout=StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text,0,text.length,textPaint,150)

staticLayout.build().draw(canvas)}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your code. Your posted code wrap the texts based on passing length but I need to wrap the json according to its keys with pretty format. Could you please help on this regards?